# Color detection in openCV - Pixel checking issue

Tags: javascript, c++, objective-c, opencv, colors

In opencCV , I got this code to detect the colour in which they check the value at every pixel , get the desired value and replace it with white and convert all the unnecessary pixels to the black . here is the code .

```
int MaxC = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < img_output.rows; i++)
{
for(int j = 0; j < img_output.cols; j++)
{
    nPixelPos = i*img_output.cols*cn + j*cn;
    nCombinedVal = (pixelPtr[nPixelPos +2]) *( 255 - pixelPtr[nPixelPos +1]);
    if (nCombinedVal > MaxC)
        MaxC = nCombinedVal;
}
}

MaxC = MaxC / 255;
for(int i = 0; i < img_output.rows; i++)
{
for(int j = 0; j < img_output.cols; j++)
{
    nPixelPos = i*img_output.cols*cn + j*cn;
    nCombinedVal = (pixelPtr[nPixelPos +2]) *( 255 - pixelPtr[nPixelPos +1]);
    nCombinedVal = (nCombinedVal/ MaxC);;
    if (nCombinedVal > 230)
    {
        pixelPtr1[nPixelPos + 0]= nCombinedVal;
        pixelPtr1[nPixelPos+ 1] = nCombinedVal;
        pixelPtr1[nPixelPos + 2]= nCombinedVal;
    }
    else
    {
        pixelPtr1[nPixelPos + 0]= 0;
        pixelPtr1[nPixelPos+ 1] = 0;
        pixelPtr1[nPixelPos + 2]= 0;
    }
}
}
```

Now my problems are :-

This code is particularly for one colour (green) I also want to make it compatible for other colours (i.e. red) .. But I dont know where should I change in this code. can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding your measurement of greenness, the lines which computes the measurement is:

```
nCombinedVal = (pixelPtr[nPixelPos +2]) *( 255 - pixelPtr[nPixelPos +1]);
```

The nPixelPos is the index to the pixel. If the image follows the OpenCV BGR convention +1 will give you the green channel and +2 gives you the red channel. If it follows the RGB convention, +1 will still be green but +2 will be blue.

<strike>To change detected color to red, my best guess would be to replace +1 with +2 and change +2 to +1 or +0. Be sure to modify both lines.</strike>

```
nCombinedVal = (pixelPtr[nPixelPos +1]) *( 255 - pixelPtr[nPixelPos +2]);
```

If you would be willing to replace the code, I would suggest a different measurement of color:

```
greenness = green - max(red, blue)
redness = red - max(green, blue)
blueness = blue - max(red, green)
```

<strike>Which would look something like this in your code:</strike>

```
for(int i = 0; i < img_output.rows; i++)
{
for(int j = 0; j < img_output.cols; j++)
{
    nPixelPos = i*img_output.cols*cn + j*cn;
    int greenness = int(pixelPtr[nPixelPos +1]) - max(pixelPtr[nPixelPos], pixelPtr[nPixelPos +2]);
    if (greeness > 10)
    {
        pixelPtr1[nPixelPos + 0] = 255;
        pixelPtr1[nPixelPos + 1] = 255;
        pixelPtr1[nPixelPos + 2] = 255;
    }
    else
    {
        pixelPtr1[nPixelPos + 0] = 0;
        pixelPtr1[nPixelPos + 1] = 0;
        pixelPtr1[nPixelPos + 2] = 0;
    }
}
}
```

**EDIT:** OpenCV stores HSV color information in reversed order and divides hue by two to fit into a byte (more details [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?highlight=cvtcolor#cvtcolor)). pixelPtr[nPixelPos +2] is therefore the hue and pixelPtr[nPixelPos +1] is the saturation. To change the color you are looking for, replace the row with something like this:

```
nCombinedVal = abs(pixelPtr[nPixelPos +2]-target_hue) *( 255 - pixelPtr[nPixelPos +1]);
```

Where target_hue is the hue you want to find divided by two.

Comment: HI Can you please tell me the OpenCV HSV convention ? As I am using HSV to find colour here .

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can refer below code which will access pixel value using mouse and display the result

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
 Mat image, src;
 char window_name[20]="Pixel Value Demo";

void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int f, void* ){
 image=src.clone();
 Vec3b pix=image.at<Vec3b>(y,x);
 int B=pix.val[0];
 int G=pix.val[1];
 int R=pix.val[2];


 char name[30];
    sprintf(name,"R=%d",R);
    putText(image,name, Point(10,130) , FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .7, Scalar(0,255,0), 2,8,false );

    sprintf(name,"G=%d",G);
    putText(image,name, Point(10,170) , FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .7, Scalar(0,255,0), 2,8,false );

    sprintf(name,"B=%d",B);
    putText(image,name, Point(10,210) , FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .7, Scalar(0,255,0), 2,8,false );

    sprintf(name,"X=%d",x);
    putText(image,name, Point(10,300) , FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .7, Scalar(0,255,0), 2,8,false );

    sprintf(name,"Y=%d",y);
    putText(image,name, Point(10,340) , FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .7, Scalar(0,255,0), 2,8,false );
 imshow( window_name, image );
}



int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  namedWindow( window_name, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

  src = imread( "ball.jpg");
  imshow( window_name, src );

  setMouseCallback( window_name, onMouse, 0 );

  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @haris .. but I need to correct the code above only .. because I have based all my code from above code .. that code is working properly .. but only for that one green colour .. so please can you help me on that .. btw I have read your so many post on openCV forum.. they helped me a lot .. thanks man :)